# Android match_parent not working as expected

Tags: android

In my layout file I use root `ScrollView`and child `LinearLayout`.

I searched about this but did't get help.
I set **match_parent** in my both parent and child view.

But there is problem with child view.

Child view not filling like parent view.

Here is image and xml code.

[image]

Layout File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:CustomTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:CustomEditTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D3D6DB"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".tabs.MyTravelTab" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background_new"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical" >

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textGPS"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                        android:text="ABC"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/gps_toggle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/gps_custom_toggle"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:textOn="" />

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textManual"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                        android:text="DEF"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerPurposeOfJourney"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:background="@drawable/dropdown_black_border"
                    android:entries="@array/purpose_of_journey" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/gpsLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/startGPSBtn"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_green_drawable_left_curve_selector"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/gps" />

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                        android:text="START GPS"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/endGPSBtn"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_red_drawable_right_curve_selector"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/end_flag" />

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                        android:text="END GPS"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                        android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_textview"
                        CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                        android:background="@drawable/textview_gray_drawable"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="DATA"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray" />

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/edtTxtDate"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
                        android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_edittext"
                        CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_drawable_right_curv_selector"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="DATA"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/manualLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                            android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_textview"
                            CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                            android:background="@drawable/textview_gray_drawable"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="DATA"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray" />

                        <com.mymv.controls.CustomEditTextView
                            android:id="@+id/edtTxtStartOdometer"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
                            android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_edittext"
                            CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_drawable_right_curv_selector"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:hint="DATA"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="6"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                            android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_textview"
                            CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                            android:background="@drawable/textview_gray_drawable"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="DATA"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray" />

                        <com.mymv.controls.CustomEditTextView
                            android:id="@+id/edtTxtEndOdometer"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
                            android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_edittext"
                            CustomEditTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_drawable_right_curv_selector"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:hint="DATA"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="6"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                        android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_textview"
                        CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                        android:background="@drawable/textview_gray_drawable"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="DATA"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray" />

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomEditTextView
                        android:id="@+id/edtTxtStartLocation"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
                        android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_edittext"
                        CustomEditTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_drawable_right_curv_selector"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="DATA"
                        android:maxLength="100"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                        android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_textview"
                        CustomTextView:typeface="Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                        android:background="@drawable/textview_gray_drawable"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="DATA"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray" />

                    <com.mymv.controls.CustomEditTextView
                        android:id="@+id/edtTxtEndLocation"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
                        android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_edittext"
                        CustomEditTextView:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_drawable_right_curv_selector"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="DATA"
                        android:maxLength="100"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/field_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_blue_border"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/viewUsage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background_yellow"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/viewTravelHistory"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background_blue"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is the point of ScrollView then?

Comment: What did you expect there?

Comment: it is not filling the entire space because the scroll view . it will only fill the space that is required for it to fill. so try using fill_parent or use the scroll view inside another layout.

Comment: Use LinearLayout as your root layout and then add ScrollView as an immediate child. I think it fills the gap

Comment: @ErAcube I also tried Root layout as linear layout and set scrollview, But same thing happens.

Comment: have you tried with fillViewport:true for scrollview?

Comment: Its working with `android:fillViewport="true"` but activity dose't scroll.

Comment: don't use the weight concepts with in scrollview,so that linearlayout works wrap content heights.

Comment: But its necessary in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `android:fillViewport="true"` in your scrollview.

Comment: Its working with `android:fillViewport="true"` but activity dose't scroll.

Comment: Because your content is less, once you have more content than area, it will start scrolling. Kindly accept the best answer :)

Comment: No content is not less. When keyboard is open Its not scrolling. And I tested in small device but content is not scroll.

Comment: I also added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` this line in android manifest file

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout inside the ScrollView is recommended to use `wrap_content` for its size.

To display the full of listview, you can:

> 1. Use `android:fillViewport="true"`attribute of ScrollView

OR

> 2. Use exactly value for width and height for LinearLayout. You can calculate it depend on you need, such as equal to screen dimensions, or equal other view size, ...

Comment: Its working with android:fillViewport="true" but activity dose't scroll.

Comment: So try the second :) you can set the height of linearLayout larger than scrollView a bit without effect to performance

Answer (score 0):

Use
android:fillViewport="true" attribute of scrollview.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport